# Trying to get field data to fit into if inarray() check

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

Just wondering if anyone can help me with this problem...
I want to be able to check if a certain ID (user for example is logged on) The ID's of these users will be pulled from a table, and then fed into an array and then checked if it is in there.

However when I pull the data the if inarray() no longer works as it would if I just typed it in straight within the code instead of pulling it.

I want to pull approved ID's through so they can access a certain link essentially!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<?php
mssql_select_db("$ins", $con);

$result = mssql_query("SELECT ID FROM Event WHERE  EventPublic LIKE 'Yes' AND EventDate >=       GETDATE() -1   ORDER BY EventDate ASC    ");


while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{



$test = "". $row['ID'] .",";

}


$tests = explode(',', $test);


if (in_array("2, 48", $tests)) {
   echo "WOO";
 }
 else
{
echo "BOO";
 }


mssql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in array should be an actual array

```
in_array(array('2', '48'), $tests)
```

also, it would be better to put

```
$tests = array();
```

before the while loop, then change the code inside the loop to read

```
$tests[] = $row['ID'];
```

then you can do away with the '$tests = explode(...' line.

Comment: Whoops, I realise that was wrong. @Brett's answer below works. If you had a large array, you could add to the array doing '$tests[$row['id']] = true', then you can use 'isset($tests[2]) || isset($tests[4])'. This would be significantly quicker on a large array (in_array is quite slow)

Answer (score 0):

Your having the issue with your in_array test because you are comparing an array and with a string in the following line:

```
if (in_array("2, 48", $tests))
```

The above line checks if the string "2, 48" exist in the array. But the array will have 2 as one element and 48 as a separate element. To fix this you can search for each element individually with something like:

```
if(in_array('2',$tests) || in_array('48',$tests))
```